# Scan a image with emgu cv

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

So i have an image that has been processed with the sobel method, and now i need to extract that image.

My problem is how can i start scanning the image from the mid line uo and down line by line, and when the number of edge is less than 60, record that coordinate to crop the image.

The image in question is a barcode, and this method should work for extracting only the bars. The problem is the implementation with emgu cv.

**Update:**

I am following the method described in this paper: http://bit.ly/HUWdcy

This question is referent to the C. Image Extraction Chapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `cv::threshold` and `cv::reduce` functions.

First wil create a binary map out of your edge image, with black on the stripes, and white on background.

Like this small example:

After edges

```
1 70  0 0 85  128 99  0
1 70  0 0 85  128 99  0
1 70  0 0 85  128 99  0
1 70  0 0 85  120 99  0
1 74  0 0 85  138 99  0
1 80  0 0 85  128 99  0
1 72  0 0 85  128 99  0
```

After threshold

```
0 255 0 0 255 255 255 0
0 255 0 0 255 255 255 0
0 255 0 0 255 255 255 0
0 255 0 0 255 255 255 0
0 255 0 0 255 255 255 0
0 255 0 0 255 255 255 0
0 255 0 0 255 255 255 0
```

Second function can be used to "project" the image on one of its dimensions, using `CV_MAX`, or `CV_SUM`, or `CV_AVG`, and you will have the barcodes stored in a row

Example for `reduce` with `SUM`:

```
0 1785 0 0 1785 1785 1785 0
```

Now, reapply a threshold:

```
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my problem now is finding the edges pf the code, i have done the image per-processing as referred in the article above an then applied the sobel operator to the image. Now to see the code edge i think i can go up and down from the middle of the image and check if pixel are equal, for the sides i know they start and end with 101, but with the pixel i read i get no such thing, just a lot of 0 and then 1.

Comment: and for which i see in your answer, you already consider the code, with no background and use the reduce method to put the matrix in only one vector, my problem with that is that i can't execute the reduce method in my project, for example cvinvoke.cvreduce(...) and img.reduce(...) don't work, i thing the parameters i am putting are wrong, if you could help with would be great.

Comment: @celsoap7 I do not have the time neither the experience with code bars to help you. I hope this is a start, and I invite you to go deeper with learning and trying.